# magento2 not showing changes in frontend

Tags: magento2, product-list

I am new in Magento 2. I want to add new custom text on listing page. I've attached a screenshot for reference.I have copy list.phtml  from

```
 /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml
```

to dafault LUMA theme

```
   app/design/frontend/Magento/Luma/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
```

I have added text in list.phtml of theme location file.my problem is that changes is not showing list page. but when i have same text changed in core list.phtml file changes is showing.

After Following commands run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy 
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: check in admin you have selecting Magento Luma Theme

Comment: @MoinMalek selected theme LUMA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using magento default luma theme that **you cannot use  Template  changes logic -**

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
```

for ***luma theme*** bcoz of this theme is register under **vendor/** folder.

In this create case, ***you should edit at core or need to  create custom  module from where you can template via layout***

This module should consist of below files:

- `app/code/app/code/{vendorname}/{Modulename}/registration.php`
- `app/code/{vendorname}/{Modulename}/composer.json`
- `app/code/{vendorname}/{Modulename}/etc/module.xml`
- `app/code/{vendorname}/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`
- `app/code/{vendorname}/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`

**catalog_category_view.xml** code should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
         <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">{vendorname}_{Modulename}::product/list.phtml</argument>
         </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body></page>
```

And  `app/design/frontend/Magento/Luma/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml` need to copy at `app/code/{vendorname}/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

Theme name should be in lower case.

```
app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
```

Please check below link.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.2-develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Catalog

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure you are in developer mode and then I try to clean pub/static and var/view_preprocessed and redeploy static content. If this doesn't work try and extend the layout. In app\design\frontend\vendor\theme\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_category_view.xml